# Why do we hear a "whistle" from a flying arrow?

Tags: acoustics

What is the cause of the *whistle* we hear from an arrow released by a bow?
It's not Doppler effect because the arrow is not making any sound - or does it while moving through air?

Comment: Altough one post may answer the question, it is better to leave the question open for at least 1 day, before you choose the best answer, so that other people can contribute with more answers. This particular case could have obtained a longer and more detailed answer.

Comment: Oh ok, next time I will not choose that quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vibrations (sound) in the air are induced by turbulence in the air due to friction between the air and the arrow.

Comment: Oh, ok - it's done sometimes... so why everytime we shoot with arrow we don't hear that whistle? Everytime there are vibrations on arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the sound of an arrow moving through the air is caused by the vibration of the flight feathers. As with fire engines or railway trains,there should be a change in pitch due to the Doppler effect when the arrow is flying toward or away from you,but as the sound of an arrow is much fainter than these other examples,not many humans have hearing sensitive enough to detect it.